# Connect C wire Lennox G16

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

[image]

I bought a new thermostat that needs the c wire. Old thermostat wasnt using the blue c and was stuffed back in the wall. Come to find out the blue c wire is not connected to the furnace. Trying to connect the blue c wire to my furnace. As you can see all the wires are connect except the blue c which is wrapped at the bottom of the picture.

Comment: Related, but probably not a duplicate: [Can I use the T terminal in my furnace as the C for a Wifi Thermostat?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/56049/33)

Answer (score 2):

Found solution. Just connected C blue wire to the T terminal on the old furnace.

Comment: The other hint is the AC wires connecting to `Y` and `T`