# How do I connect a C wire or C adapter to an older Lennox furnace with no terminal strip?

Tags: lennox

I have an older Lennox Conservator 3 G16 with no terminal strip. How do I connect a C wire or C adapter? From what I have seen online nothing matches my furnace.

[image]

Comment: No sorry that's all I have at the moment

Comment: Does this help? [Connect C wire Lennox G16](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119941/connect-c-wire-lennox-g16)

Comment: No I do not have a panel like that in my furnace.  I believe they call it the terminal strip or control panel

Comment: Where is your thermostat that controls it now ?

Comment: The thermial strip is in the top left corner

Comment: FYI, furnace connections are usually in the lower compartment, not in the burner area. Follow them in from outside the cabinet.

Comment: @Ruskes, those look like safety device wires. The t-stat board is down below.

Comment: thank you for the pointers, Not at place with furnace now but will look this evening