# How should I wire my thermostat considering the existing adapter device?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

Currently 18-4 is running from furnace to thermostat. I should be able just to use the T terminal to get power but there's some kind of funky adapter on it.

[image]

Any know what the adapter is for and how to wire around it?

Comment: Can you post a wiring diagram for your furnace/air-handler?

Comment: Thank you for responding - I'll look for it.  The more I think about it though the more I'm thinking I just match up the existing wiring and run the C wire off the T terminal as originally planned.    Here's an earlier post about wiring up a lenox.    https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/56049/can-i-use-the-t-terminal-in-my-furnace-as-the-c-for-a-wifi-thermostat?noredirect=1&lq=1